# Как исправить ошибку java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl?

Tags: java, soap, java-11

Разрабатываю приложение на `java 11`. Приложение взаимодействует с другой системой. При работе возникают такие ошибки:

```
    javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found
  at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
  at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
  at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[?:?]
  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:600) ~[?:?]
  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:678) ~[?:?]
  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:737) ~[?:?]
  at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:159) ~[?:?]
  at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[?:?]
  at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:233) ~[?:?]
  at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497) ~[?:?]
  at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:661) ~[?:?]
...
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found
  at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder$1.createException(FactoryFinder.java:61) ~[jaxws-api-2.3.1.jar:?]
  at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder$1.createException(FactoryFinder.java:58) ~[jaxws-api-2.3.1.jar:?]
  at javax.xml.ws.spi.ServiceLoaderUtil.newInstance(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:103) ~[jaxws-api-2.3.1.jar:?]
  at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:112) ~[jaxws-api-2.3.1.jar:?]
  at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:96) ~[jaxws-api-2.3.1.jar:?]
  at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:112) ~[jaxws-api-2.3.1.jar:?]
...
  at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[?:?]
  at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654) ~[?:?]
  at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[?:?]
  at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:290) ~[?:?]
  at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:746) ~[?:?]
  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290) ~[?:?]
  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020) ~[?:?]
  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656) ~[?:?]
  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594) ~[?:?]
  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:177) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl
  at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583) ~[?:?]
  at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[?:?]
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[?:?]
  at javax.xml.ws.spi.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:90) ~[jaxws-api-2.3.1.jar:?]
  at javax.xml.ws.spi.ServiceLoaderUtil.safeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:123) ~[jaxws-api-2.3.1.jar:?]
  at javax.xml.ws.spi.ServiceLoaderUtil.newInstance(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:101) ~[jaxws-api-2.3.1.jar:?]
  at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:112) ~[jaxws-api-2.3.1.jar:?]
  at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:96) ~[jaxws-api-2.3.1.jar:?]
  at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:112) ~[jaxws-api-2.3.1.jar:?]
...
  at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[?:?]
  at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654) ~[?:?]
  at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[?:?]
  at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:290) ~[?:?]
  at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:746) ~[?:?]
  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290) ~[?:?]
  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020) ~[?:?]
  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656) ~[?:?]
  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594) ~[?:?]
  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:177) ~[?:?]
```

Пробовал разные зависимости в `maven`, и ничего не помогает:

```
<!-- SOAP and XML -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <!--               <dependency>
                         <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
                         <artifactId>javax.jws-api</artifactId>
                         <version>1.1</version>
                     </dependency>
     -->
        <!--        <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                    <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.1</version>
                </dependency>-->
        <!--        <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.1</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                </dependency>-->
        <!--        <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.1</version>
                </dependency>-->


        <!--        <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                    <artifactId>webservices-rt</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0</version>
                </dependency>-->
```

В интернете тоже много искал, но решение пока не нашёл

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49107375/getting-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-xml-internal-ws-spi-providerim

Comment: @DeMmAge Смотрел, пробовал - не помогло. К тому же у меня версии другие - джавы и томката

Comment: https://microsoftadvertising.uservoice.com/forums/82363-microsoft-advertising-feature-suggestions/suggestions/37373089-java-11-support

Comment: @DeMmAge спасибо за старания, но нет, не помогло =(

Comment: @MaxLich приложите кусок кода, чтобы можно было воспроизвести

Answer (score 1):

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xml-apis/xml-apis/2.0.2

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xml-apis/xml-apis -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```